# WCF rest service 403.16 Error

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

Until today my wcf rest service hosted on IIS 8 with SSL protocol was working perfectly, but now I started getting `HTTP Error 403.16 - Forbidden The client certificate used for this request is not trusted by the Web server.`. I have no idea why this has happened and keeps happening.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you give further detail? Is this a post, put or get?

Comment: The problem is solved ( no idea how, I didn't do anything special ).

Comment: Is it a DigiCert certificate?

Answer (score 1):

I have a wcf service which uses certificate authentication and supports both REST and SOAP request. It was working as expected, but recently 'REST' requests have stopped working (while SOAP continued working) and gets me 403.16 error. This service hosted on IIS 8 on my local machine - and haven't been used each day.

Back to problem - in this period I've been added some certificate to my Trusted root authorities for some other test purposes. This certificate hasn't been self-signed (child certificate / 'issued to' is different than 'issued by'), and because of this certificate my service stopped working (actually REST part only).

> After removing non self-signed certificate from trusted root - problem has been
>   solved!

So, my suggestion is to check whether 'trusted root' contains not 'self-signed certificates'.